# PHP, MYSQL, AJAX - filter multiple select's

Tags: php, jquery

There are tons of questions about this, but none of them really deal with Select Options.

My question: I have 4 selects all with multiple values pulled from the database. I want to database information to display, and as the user selects each item it only shows what the user has selected.

For example: Box 1 - A (Show all A) box 2 - year (Show all A with year, if none then display "Nothing matches your search" box 3 ect...

My Code:

```
if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM DB";

 if(isset($_POST["producer"]))
 {
  $producer_filter = implode("','", $_POST["producer"]);
  $query .= "
   WHERE producer=('".$producer_filter."')
  ";
 }
 if(isset($_POST["size"]))
 {
  $size_filter = implode("','", $_POST["size"]);
  $query .= " OR size=('".$size_filter."')
  ";
 }
 if(isset($_POST["model"]))
 {
  $model_filter = implode("','", $_POST["model"]);
  $query .= "OR model=('".$model_filter."')";
 }
 if(isset($_POST["year"]))
 {
  $year_filter = implode("','", $_POST["year"]);
  $query .= "OR year=('".$year_filter."')";
 }

 $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 $total_row = $statement->rowCount();
 $output = '';
 if($total_row > 0)
 {
  foreach($result as $row)
  {
   $output .= '
   <tr><td>'.$row['producer'].'</td>
   <td>'.$row['size'].'</td>
   <td>'.$row['model'].'</td>
   <td>'.$row['year'].'</td>
   <td>'.$row['salesman'].'</td>
   <td>'.$row['country'].'</td></tr>

   ';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  $output = 'Please User Filters to Search for Parts';
 }
 echo $output;
}
```

And then my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        filter_data();


        function filter_data() {

            const action = 'fetch_data';
            let producer = get_filter('producer');
            let size = get_filter('size')
            let model = get_filter('model')
            let year = get_filter('year')

            $.ajax({
                url: "search.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    action: action,
                    producer: producer,
                    size: size,
                    model: model,
                    year: year
                },

                success: function(data) {
                    $('.prod').html(data);
                },
            });
        }

        function get_filter(class_name) {
            var filter = [];
            $('.' + class_name).each(function() {
                filterData = $(this).val();
                filter.push(filterData)

            });
            console.log(filter)
            return filter;
        }

        $('.form-control').change(function() {
            filter_data();
        });

    });
```

This works, however, it displays everything regardless if it matches my filters or not. Is there something I can add in the Jquery?

I appreciate all the help.

Comment: If the php is returning all the data, there's something wrong with the sql query. Can you verify that the parameters are being sent? Looks like none of the `isset` are being triggered, because at first glance I'd say that the query should return no records, you should use `IN` instead of `=` in your conditions. If the php is failing, `success` may not be being triggered.

Comment: So, I am getting the information in the table no problem, however if I choose Option A and B, I get all the data containing those, plus whatever doesn't. I want to be able to sort for an item that has all 4 boxes information. So A, B C and D and if it doesnt match ALL of those then display an error to the user. I changed the = to in :)

Comment: Oh, duh, you are using `OR`. If it has to match all conditions should be `AND`. And you might need to change `isset` to `!empty`.

Comment: Tried this, now it does not filter at all.

Comment: Nevermind, it works. :D I just didnt have the right error text :D